# Is there a Xamarin event I can attach to for when a page finishes being laid out?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin.Forms page that loads fine. If I click a button on the page that causes the Content to be changed, the whole UI shifts a little bit. I am assuming this is happening due the equivalent of a ForceLayout happening when I change the Content page. It is a fairly complex page, with a couple RelativeLayouts inside a StackLayout.

After this happens once, it never happens again, interestingly enough. So I am thinking if I do a ForceLayout somewhere, or even just reset the Content twice on load it might fix it for me. The trouble is I don't know where to make that happen. If I try it in the constructor it does not help. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my answer. I just set the content a second time in the Appearing event. Problem goes away. I love Xamarin but the layouts in forms feel like quite a hack sometimes, particularly RelativeLayouts.